# How to get Enum type from a Enum value in macro? e.g. Fruit::Apple=>Fruit?

Tags: rust

I have a lot of similar error handling code like below:

```
if let Err(stderr) = result.as_ref() {  
    if let Some(err_kind) = &stderr.downcast_ref::<IoError>() {
       if IoError::FileNotFound == *err_kind {
            ...... // handle error here
       }
}
```

to make it shorter, I wrote a macro as following:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! if_error_then {
    (
        $result:ident, 
        $error_type:ident, 
        $error_value:path,
        $handler:block
    )
    =>
    {
        if let Err(stderr) = $result.as_ref() { 
            if let Some(err_kind) = stderr.downcast_ref::<$error_type>() {
                if $error_value == *err_kind {
                    $handler
                }
            }
        }
        
    };
}
```

so the original code can be written like:

```
if_error_then!(result, IoError, IoError:FileNotFound, {
        ...
});
```

As you can see, `IoError` shows twice. How to change the macro to make it shorter like:

```
if_error_then!(result, IoError:FileNotFound, {
        ...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, it looks like we can use a `path` and `ident` separated by `::`:

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! if_error_then {
    (
        $result:ident, 
        $error:path :: $value:ident,
        $handler:block
    )
    =>
    {
        if let Err(stderr) = $result.as_ref() { 
            if let Some(err_kind) = stderr.downcast_ref::<$error>() {
                if $error::$value == *err_kind {
                    $handler
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

But this doesn't work for two reasons:

1. `path` cannot be followed by `::` (because `path` itself can contain `::`).
2. Once we captured the path, we cannot append an `ident` to it - it is already complete as a `path` (it has invisible parentheses), and only proc macro can break it.

If we only ever use one-identifier paths, we can just use `ident` for it:

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! if_error_then {
    (
        $result:ident, 
        $error:ident :: $value:ident,
        $handler:block
    )
    =>
    {
        if let Err(stderr) = $result.as_ref() { 
            if let Some(err_kind) = stderr.downcast_ref::<$error>() {
                if $error::$value == *err_kind {
                    $handler
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

If, however, we use fully-qualified paths, we need another way. We cannot use `$($error:ident)::+ :: $value:ident`, because this will create an ambiguity. There are multiple ways to solve that, but the easiest will be to use a different separator, for example `:` (one colon instead of two):

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! if_error_then {
    (
        $result:ident, 
        $($error:ident)::+ : $value:ident,
        $handler:block
    )
    =>
    {
        if let Err(stderr) = $result.as_ref() { 
            if let Some(err_kind) = stderr.downcast_ref::<$($error)::+>() {
                if $($error)::+::$value == *err_kind {
                    $handler
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

if_error_then!(result, IoError:FileNotFound, {
        // ...
});
```